# How do you add postgresql connection string using kubernetes yaml file

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, minikube

**I am deploying PostgreSQL cluster using kubernetes runnung 3 Instance How do you add postgresql connection string url by using kubernetes yaml file**

> postgresql://bigdata:bigdata@dbhost1:5432,dbhost2:5432/bigdata?target_session_attrs=primary

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<database_host>:<port>/<database_name>
```

Credentials will need to be managed via Secrets.

Comment: in which part i can add this in yaml file ?

Comment: It depends on your application; please add the YAML files in the question core.